# Pentaho Kettle Kitchen can't find plugin

Tags: java, etl, kettle, vertica

I've created and ETL for pentaho kettle which successfully runs using Spoon.
But when I try to use Kitchen I get following error:

> Unexpected error occurred while launching entry [OLTP to Vertica (Copy
>   Table).0]
>
> Unexpected error during transformation metadata load
>
> Missing plugins found while loading a transformation
>
> Step : VerticaBulkLoader
>
> ```
>     at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:859)
>     at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:596)
>     at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJobRunner.run(JobEntryJobRunner.java:71)
> ```
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I've tried to set both KETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES and KETTLE_PLUGIN_CLASSES.
Kettle version is 5.0.1.
Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Vertica bulk loader isn't installed by default. Did you install it?

Comment: What do you mean by "installed"? I just copied it to the plugins folder inside Pentaho Kettle installation folder

Comment: that's what I mean by installed. make sure you're copying into the right destination, though. I believe it should go into plugins/steps.

Comment: yeah, it just needs to be copied to the folder it looks in for plugins

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Kitchen can't find the plugin you've added.
Proper installation would entail on placing the plugin within a folder, within the following folder:

`versions/pdi-<yourversion>/plugins/steps`

Use the dummy step for reference:

```
versions/pdi-<yourversion>/plugins/steps
|_ DummyPlugin
   |_ DPL.png
   |_ dummy.jar
   |_ plugin.xml
```

I hope it helps.